# XAML Refactoring - How to extract common markup

Tags: wpf, xaml, refactoring

I have some xaml pasted at the end of this question. It's from a resource file in my project.

The HierarchicalDataTemplate and the DataTemplate share exactly the same structure. Is there a way to extract the common parts and reference it in?

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChapterViewModel}"
                          x:Key="ChapterOutcomesTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Chapter.Outcomes}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AssignedOutcomeTemplate}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Height="16"
            Width="16"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Source="{Binding Source={x:Static images:DocumentImages.Outcomes}}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsOutcomesAssigned, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}, Mode=OneWay}"
                   />
        <Image Height="16"
            Width="16"
            RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Margin="5,0,0,0"
            Source="{Binding Source={x:Static images:DocumentImages.Chapter}}" 
                   />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Chapter.Name}"
            Margin="5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Height="16"
            Width="16"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Source="{Binding Source={x:Static images:DocumentImages.Outcomes}}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsOutcomesAssigned, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Image Height="16"
            Width="16"
            RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Margin="5,0,0,0"
            Source="{Binding Source={x:Static images:DocumentImages.Chapter}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Chapter.Name}"
            Margin="5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>

</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  Define the content that's due to be shared as a control template, then use it in both templates:

```
<!-- New control template -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ChapterAndItemTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Margin="0"
           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
           SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
           Source="{Binding Source={x:Static images:DocumentImages.Outcomes}}"
           Visibility="{Binding IsOutcomesAssigned, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Margin="5,0,0,0"
           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
           SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
           Source="{Binding Source={x:Static images:DocumentImages.Chapter}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Chapter.Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
  </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChapterViewModel}"
                          x:Key="ChapterOutcomesTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Chapter.Outcomes}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AssignedOutcomeTemplate}">
  <!-- Used here... -->
  <Control Template="{StaticResource ChapterAndItemTemplate}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
  <!-- ...and here -->
  <Control Template="{StaticResource ChapterAndItemTemplate}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi Drew. Are you aware of any tools that help do refactorings like this? Similar to how resharper might do it in code.. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl - I haven't seen any tools for this yet but I'm sure they'll surface soon.  Might be a fun project for someone wanting to try out the ReSharper plugin API.

Comment: @DrewNoakes I guess it won't be wise to keep waiting :-)

Comment: Is there a feature to do this automatically?  Something similar along the lines of extract to template control?